# Can't get meteor to work with react and npm

Tags: meteor, reactjs, npm, react-bootstrap

I am trying to get meteor to work with react-bootstrap npm package, and I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: _reactDom2.default.findDOMNode is not a function` no matter what I try.

For that purpose I use AdamBrodzinski/meteor-react-boilerplate, and while it works fine, it doesn't work for me when I try to add additional packages from npm. I tried material-ui too, and I got exactly the same error as I do now.

I also followed this tutorial: http://react-in-meteor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/client-npm/

My repository I get an error in is: https://github.com/vincaslt/meteor-chess

both\pages\Game.jsx is the file that contains my changes. I also made sure I referenced bootstrap components in app.browserify.js:

```
Button = require('react-bootstrap/lib/Button')
Modal = require('react-bootstrap/lib/Modal')
```

I tried importing react-dom as npm package in the project, but that doesn't change anything regarding the error.

Comment: Try to setup React as an NPM module. Not as a meteor package like this : `npm i --save react react-dom`, `import React from 'react';` : https://voice.kadira.io/getting-started-with-meteor-1-3-and-react-15e071e41cd1#.i3pkunjjk

Comment: I will try to use meteor 1.13, currently I'm using custom package to allow me to use meteor 1.12.1 with npm, and most likely that's causing me all those problems.

Comment: Have you considered filing an issue on  AdamBrodzinski/meteor-react-boilerplate?